# Data compression in RDBMS like Oracle, MySQL etc

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, in-memory-database, compression

I was reading about in-memory database which incorporates a feature like data compression. Using that, instead of storing first name, last name, father's name etc. values as it is in the column (which leads to a lot of data duplication and waste of disk storage), it creates a dictionary and attribute vector table for each column, so that only unique values are stored in dictionary and its corresponding attribute vector is stored in original table.
Clear advantage of this approach is that it a lot of space by removing overhead of data duplication.

I want to know:

1. Does RDBMS like Oracle, MySQL etc. implicitly follow this approach when they store the data on disk? Or when we use these RDBMS we have to implement the same if we want to take advantage of the same?
2. As we know there is no free lunch, so I would like to understand what are the trade-offs if developer implements above explained data compression approach? One I can think of is that in order to fetch the data from database, I will have to make a join between my dictionary table and main table. Isn't it?

Please share your thoughts and inputs.

Comment: For Mysql (specifically InnoDB) what they do is [explained in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-compression-internals.html) - just zlib

Comment: @fvu Thanks. I would need information about its default MyISAM Storage Engine and other cases like Oracle.

Comment: Google is your friend, my friend :) By a last one for Oracle here: http://www.oracle.com/au/products/database/11g-compression-198295.html. For Postgres you could read about TOAST.

Comment: @fvu Thanks buddy. I agree. I did my home work and have idea about it, but wanted to brain storm and take others view about it, so put it on SO.

Comment: This question is probably too broad.  Just for Oracle there are 5 different types of compression I can think of off the top of my head.

Comment: @JonHeller Thank you for your inputs. Ok, then, does Oracle do something similar of what I explained or that's something only developer has to do? I mean having a dictionary and attribute vector. While I was reading about in-memory, I saw that it was explained as a technique for data compression, so I was wondering about it in context of RDBMS.

Comment: The Oracle documents have a complete reference on this, and it's a very complex issue. I voted to close as being too broad.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Not a problem, thanks.

Comment: @hagrawal Yes, Oracle can do that.  The most common method is basic table compression - when you create a table with the `compress` keyword (and no other compression options).  Oracle stores data within each block, usually about 8KB.  [This article](http://allthingsoracle.com/compression-oracle-basic-table-compression/) by Jonathan Lewis is a good introduction to table compression.  Other types of compression are OLTP compression, basic index compression, advanced(?) index compression, in-memory compression, and secure files compression.  You could literally write a book on the subject.

Comment: @JonHeller Thanks a lot for your inputs, this would be helpful. I think by now I have made most possible from this post. Now even if it is closed after one more vote, which is looking very imminent to me, its kind of ok.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is  based on my understanding of your query. It appears that you are mixing up two concepts : **data normalisation** and **data storage optimisation**.

**Data Normalisation** : This is a process that needs to be undertaken by the application developer. Here pieces of data that would need to be stored repeatedly are stored only once and are referenced using their identifiers which would typically be integers. This way the database consumes spaces only as much as needed to store the repeating data once. This is a common practice while storing string and variable length data into the database tables. In order to retrieve data, the application would have to perform joins between the related tables. And this process contributes directly to application performance depending on the manner in which the related tables are designed.

**Data storage optimisation** : This is what is handled by the RDBMS itself. This involves various steps like maintaining the B-Tree structures to hold data, compressing data before storage, managing the free space within the data files etc. Different RDBMS systems would handle them in different ways (some of them patented and proprietary while others are more general); however when we are speaking of RDBMS like Oracle and MySQL you can be assured that they would follow the best in class storage algorithms to efficiently store this data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Your information is helpful, however I do not agree with what you put in "Data Normalisation". Database normalization is all about organizing database table and column in such way to a have least redundancy. What I am talking about is compressing the data. What I want to know is that if dev doesn't do the data compression I explained then would it be done by database? From what I could understand till now db's compress data in other way but not the way I explained. It looks to be be that this has to be done by dev (if needed after knowing pros and cons), as explained by you.

Comment: Lets see what other have to say and their experience about it.